# Regex Lookbehind in Javascript Alternatives

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm trying to use the following regex in JS:

`(?<=@[A-Z|a-z]+,)\s|(?<=@[A-Z|a-z]+,\s[A-Z|a-z]+)\s(?=\[[A-Z|a-z]+\])`

which translates to:

match all spaces which are preceded by :

- `@`
- followed by any number of characters in the range `A-Z` or `a-z`
- followed by a comma

OR

match all spaces which are preceded by:

- `@`
- followed by any number of characters in the range `A-Z` or `a-z`
- followed by a comma
- followed by a space
- followed by any number of characters in the range `A-Z` or `a-z`

AND are succeeded by:

- `[`
- followed by any number of characters in the range `A-Z` or `a-z`
- `]`

However, JS doesn't support lookbehind. Is there any alternative for supporting the above regex in JS or any npm library I can use instead?

So if we have a sentence like
`Hi my name is @John, Doe [Example] and I am happy to be here` that should become
`Hi my name is @John,Doe[Example] and I am happy to be here`.
Also, if we have something like
`Hi my name is @John, Smith Doe [Example]`, that should become
`Hi my name is @John,SmithDoe[Example]`.

Comment: JavaScript _does_ support look-behind, as of ECMAScript 2018. Almost no browser does, though.

Comment: Are you trying to replace something?

Comment: @revo trying to replace those spaces, yes

Comment: Convert your lookbehinds to capturing groups and while doing a replacement put a backreference for them to have them in results.

Comment: @revo would you be able to post an example as an answer - not exactly sure how to do that

Comment: The only problem with a simple conversion approach is that these two alternative patterns are overlapping. You should either run replacements until no match, or find a way to make them match distinct whitespaces. See https://regex101.com/r/MAalM5/1 as an example work-around.

Comment: @Alk There always has to be the text in square brackets at the end?

Comment: its optional but not required, so it should also match examples like `@match, match` and convert that to `@match,match`

Comment: What about `Hi my name is @López de la Cerda, Antonio Gabriel Hugo Davíd [Author]`?

Comment: @HerrSerker `Hi my name is @LópezdelaCerda,AntonioGabrielHugoDavíd[Author]`

Comment: @Alk in this case you cannot match and replace it in one go. First we have to find all the matches in the text and only then we can replace the spaces in the matches

Comment: @HerrSerker that's fine, we can do it in multiple steps

Comment: But `@López de la Cerda, Antonio Gabriel Hugo Davíd` (without the `[Author]` will become `@LópezdelaCerda,Antonio Gabriel Hugo Davíd`

Comment: @HerrSerker that's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated my answer on new input

```js
console.clear();

var inputEl = document.querySelector('#input')
var outputEl = document.querySelector('#output')

function rep (e) {
  var input = e.target.value;
  var reg = /@([a-z]+?\s*?)+,(\s+[a-z]+)+(\s\[[a-z]+\])?/gim



  matches = input.match(reg);
  var output = input;

  if (matches) {
    replaceMap = new Map()
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      var m = matches[i]
        .replace(/\[/, '\\[')
        .replace(/\]/, '\\]')
      replaceMap.set(m, matches[i].replace(/\s+/gm, ''))
    }
    for (var [s,r] of replaceMap) {
      output = output.replace(new RegExp(s, 'gm'), r) 
    }
  }

  outputEl.textContent = output
}

inputEl.addEventListener('input', rep)
inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Input</h3>
<textarea id="input">@Lopez de la Cerda, Antonio Gabriel Hugo David [Author]. I'm the father of @Marquez, Maria</textarea>
<h3>Output (initially empty)</h3>
<p id="output"></p>
<h3>Expected result (on initial input)</h3>
<p>@LopezdelaCerda,AntonioGabrielHugoDavid[Author]. I'm the father of @Marquez,Maria</p>
```

## Backup of old answer content (for historical reasons)

It works at least in Chrome with this regex:

```
/(?<=@[a-z]+,)\s+(?![a-z]+\s+\[[a-z]+\])|(?<=(@[a-z]+,\s[a-z]+))\s+(?=\[[a-z]+\])/gmi
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/elTkRe/4

But you can't use it in PCRE because it is not allowed to have quantifiers in lookbehinds. They must be of fixed width. See the errors to the right here: https://regex101.com/r/ZC3XmX/2

#### Solution without look behinds and look aheads

```js
console.clear();

var reg = /(@[A-Za-z]+,\s[A-Za-z]+)(\s+)(\[[A-Za-z]+\])|(@[A-Z|a-z]+,)(\s+)/gm

var probes = [
  '@gotAMatch,     <<<',
  '@LongerWithMatch,        <<<',
  '@MatchHereAsWell,    <<<',
  '@Yup,         <<<<',
  '@noMatchInThisLine,<<<<<',
  '@match, match    [match]<<<<<<<',
  '@    noMatchInThisLine,    <<<<'
]

for (var i in probes) {
  console.log(probes[i].replace(reg, '$1$3$4'))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why does it match spaces after `[fsadsd]` in the live demo?

Comment: @HerrSerker it should also match the space after the first match in `@match, match    [match]<<<<<<<`...that should become `@match,match[match]<<<<<<<`

Comment: @alk That's not how I understand it. Not all space should be replaced, but only those preceded or preceded and succeeded by the given patterns. In the second pattern the space is in the prefix and not in the match to be replaced (deleted)

Comment: @Alk your description in the original question is misleading. You should have given examples of input and the expected output

Comment: @HerrSerker in that example we have a space which is preceded by `@[a-z|A-Z]+` therefore it should also be replaced. So if we have a sentence like `Hi my name is @John, Doe [Example] and I am happy to be here` that should become `Hi my name is @John,Doe[Example] and I am happy to be here` - does that make more sense? Also, if we have something like `Hi my name is @John, Smith Doe [Example]`, that should become `Hi my name is @John,SmithDoe[Example]`

Comment: Please add those examples in your Question

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is converting lookbehinds to capturing groups in order to include them in replacement string (note that case-insensitive flag (`i`) is set):

```
(@[a-z]+,)([\t ]*([a-z]+)[\t ]*(?=\[[a-z]+\])|[\t ]+)
```

Replace with `$1$3` if you want to remove those spaces.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sXM3Dk/5)

Comment: how come in your demo, the space after foo in the second example does not get removed - it should become `@foo,bar[john]`

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: thanks - is it difficult to adapt this to also handle cases like this `@foo, bar foo [john]` -> `@foo,barfoo[john]` so essentially have any number of possible words before the `[john]` part

Comment: You have to use two `replace` calls then `str.replace(/@[a-z]+,([ \t]*[a-z]+)+(\s\[[a-z]+\])?/g, function($0) { return $0.replace(/\s+/g, ''); })`

Answer (score 0):

Just update your Node.js version. Lookbehind assertions are part of ECMAScript 2018 and are already implemented in Chromium and Node.js. According to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/, Chromium 70 and Node.js 8.10 have this feature.

I just tested it in my browser and in Node.js (v8.11) and can confirm that:

```
node -e "console.log('nothing@xyz, bla'.match(/(?<=@[A-Za-z]+,)\s+/))"
```

If you can't update you have to use other strategies like capture and replace which should not be a big issue with a positive lookbehind (negatives are harder):

```
const hit = 'nothing@xyz, bla'.match(/(@[A-Za-z]+,)\s+/)
hit[0].replace(hit[1])
```

If nothing else works, take a look at this project which tries to implement Lookbehind (I haven't tested it): http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind